# Why getElementsByClassName do not work in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, element, mozilla

I am trying to get an element of a webpage by using getElementsByClassName. I typed in firebug console

```
getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

and it returns with

```
ReferenceError: getElementsByClassName is not defined
```

I read in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) that firefox supports getElementsByClassName. I have updated firefox. Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Doesn't the page clearly say: *"Get all elements that have a class of 'test': `document.getElementsByClassName('test');`"* ?

Comment: @FelixKling : Carelessness from my side. Will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the correct format. It is a method of the `document` object.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

Answer (score 1):

Its  like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassName')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a method of `window` object then you can directly call those methods like:

```
console.log()
```

But if it is a method of any other object you have to call the method like object.methodName()
Since `getElementsByClassName` is a method of `document` object you have to call it as

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  rootElement.getElementsByClassName('names');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div clsss="myclass"></div>

var classElementArray=document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
 window.onload=function() {
      var holder =  document.getElementsByClassName('holder');

        for (var i=0; i<holder.length; i++) { 
            holder[i].innerHTML='<span>' + holder[i].className + '</span> ';
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="holder">

    </div>
</div>
```

You may forward by link:

http://jsfiddle.net/QP3Ky/